# Best approach to toggle app availability in azure?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-kubernetes-service, flask

I have an azure webapp based on a docker image that implements an image processing API and is expensive to leave active 24/7.  I'm wondering if there's an easy-to-manage way to auto-scale from 0 to 1 instances when we need it, and auto-shutdown after some period of inactivity.  AKS seems like one option but maybe it's overkill?

I also considered azure functions but since we're using a custom docker image it wasn't clear to me if I can provision an on-demand instance.

The API app runs in the background to respond to requests from a thin Flask app, and the Flask app has a background Celery task thread, so I could take on the task of toggling API availability from the Celery thread. This seems doable but also feels a lot like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Serverless](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/cloud-computing-dictionary/what-is-serverless-computing/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20serverless%20computing%3F,required%20to%20run%20the%20code.). The app will be auto-scaled up if there's a demand.